# Не могу повторить запрос post в python

Tags: python, http, charles

Пытаюсь сделать утилиту для взаимодействия с Яндекс Маркетом. там есть ajax кнопка для генерации отчета. Она генерирует отчет и выдает ссылку на него.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке повторить запрос через Python, я получаю Bad Request, хотя запрос 100% идентичен тому что идет из браузера.

```
    import requests

cookies = {
    #здесь кукисы
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'partner.market.yandex.ru',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4JUdGzvrMFDWrUUwY3toJATSeNwjn54LkCnKBPRzDuhzi5vSepHfUckJNxRL2gjkNrSqtCoRUrEDAgRwsQvVCjZbRyFTLRNyDmT1a1boZVaccept: */*',
    'origin': 'https://partner.market.yandex.ru',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://partner.market.yandex.ru/supplier/23309133/stat/stocks-by-shipment',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('r', 'mbiPartner/asyncReports/generateReport:resolveGenerateReport'),
)

json_data = {
    'params': [
        {
            'campaignId': ,
            'businessId': ,
            'reportParams': {
                'reportDate': '2022-02-13',
            },
            'reportType': 'STOCKS_BY_SUPPLY',
        },
    ],
    'path': '/supplier/23309133/stat/stocks-by-shipment',
}

response = requests.post('https://partner.market.yandex.ru/api/resolve/', headers=headers, params=params, cookies=cookies, json=json_data)

print(response.reason)
```

Если же я пытаюсь повторить запрос через http дебагер Charles, он сразу же выдает ошибку
Это оригинальный запрос из браузера Chrome:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот при попытке повторить такой же запрос но уже в дебагере Charles:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось в headers.
Необходимо было указать параметры в точности как при запросе из хрома, Charles обрезал Headers почему то.
Что бы это сделать надо открыть Network инспектор в Chrome и скопировать запрос Copy as Curl ( bash) а дальше можно либо вручную сделать запрос либо через curlconverter передалть курл в python request